# Can't increase upload_max_filesize

Tags: server, php, nginx, php-fpm

I am having problems increasing my size limit to upload files into my WordPress site.  I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a VPS server with with Nginx, MariaDB and PHP-FPM.

I checked PHP by making a file to call `phpinfo()`.

It shows the location on the `php.ini` file (`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`).
However after I edit it, and change the `upload_max_filesize` up, and restart the ngixn server, it does not change from `2M`.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you restart the php-fpm service ?

Comment: FPM uses php.ini syntax for its configuration file - php-fpm.conf, and pool configuration files.  So, you may search for a `php-fpm.conf` file

Comment: I did not restart php-fpm service.  How do I do that?    I thought restarting nginx would be enough, but I bet that is the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in php-fpm.conf that has to do with the upload limit.

Comment: did you add an `upload_max_filesize` directive ?

Comment: I was able to find out to restart php-fpm:  systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service

Comment: after restarting, the changes took effect.... Thanks!!!

Comment: in my case *sudo service php7.2-fpm restart*

Answer (score 1):

FPM uses php.ini syntax for its configuration file - php-fpm.conf, and pool configuration files
You may add the directive to `php-fpm.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf
```

Insert a line (example for 10M)

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Answer (score 0):

For these changes to take effect, you have to restart the `php7.2-fpm` service:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```